# what does " if (! nullableBool.Value ) " mean?

Tags: c#

I try to code the Nullable value concept in C#, but don't know what does  "if (!i.value)" means or what return, Is it supposed to be "true" or what?

```
class CSharp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool? i = false;
            
            if(!i.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("false");
            }
            else if(i==true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("null");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on nullables? Do you understand what `.Value` does? Do you understand what the `!` operator does? In this case,`!i.Value` would evaluate to true, yes.

Comment: i.Value turns the bool? into a bool, if the bool is null then an Exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

If `.Value` doesn't exist, this will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. If you want to check if the variable has a value, use the `HasValue` attribute instead.

You could do something like this:

```
class CSharp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool? i = false;
        
        if(!i.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("null");
        }
        else if(i.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("false");
        }
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: This makes sense, the original author of the code obviously didn't know what they were doing.

Comment: thanks 
but what (i.Value) means or what will return  ?

Comment: @TheGeek If it isn't null (`HasValue` is true), then `.Value` contains the value of the underlying type (the value you would get from i as a variable if it weren't a Nullable type).